# What will be the regular expression for below requirement in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

**Criteria:** 

any word that start with a and end with b having middle char digit. this word should not be on the line which start with char '#'

**Given string:**

```
a1b a2b a3b
#a4b a5b a6b
 a7b a8b a9b
```

**Expected output:**

```
a1b 
a2b 
a3b
a7b 
a8b 
a9b
```

**regex:** ?i need it for javascipt.

**So far tried below thing:**

```
var text_content =above_mention_content
var reg_exp = /^[^#]?a[0-9]b/gmi;
var matched_text = text_content.match(reg_exp);
console.log(matched_text);

Getting below output:
```

[ 'a1b', ' a7b' ]

Comment: I didn't down vote your question, but at least show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: ok..thanks for the feedback..i will update my question with my effort

Comment: @hamism updated the question...if u have any idea..pls share..

Comment: @Vikash: Check my approach: match what you do not need, and match and capture what you need.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i checked ur suggestion, it is working absolutely right..as expected..thank u for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `/^[^#]?a[0-9]b/gmi` will match multiple occurrences of the pattern matching the start of line, then 1 or 0 chars other than `#`, then `a`, digit and `b`. No checking for a whole word, nor actually matching words farther than at the beginning of  a string.

You may use a regex that will match lines starting with `#` and match *and capture* the words you need in other contexts:

```js
var s = "a1b a2b a3b\n#a4b a5b a6b\n a7b a8b a9b";
var res = [];
s.replace(/^[^\S\r\n]*#.*|\b(a\db)\b/gm, function($0,$1) {
  if ($1) res.push($1);
});
console.log(res);
```

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of a line (as `m` multiline modifier makes `^` match the line start)
- `[^\S\r\n]*` - 0+ horizontal whitespaces
- `#.*` - a `#` and any 0+ chars up to the end of a line
- `|` - or
- `\b` - a leading word boundary
- `(a\db)`  -  Group 1 capturing `a`, a digit, a `b`
- `\b` - a trailing word boundary.

Inside the `replace()` method, a callback is used where the `res` array is populated with the contents of Group 1 only.

Comment: wow...Thank u so much...This is much more helpfull..so is it not possible with just the regex..that will fit in my given code scenario.

Comment: You cannot skip whole lines and match individual words with 1 matching  JS regex. In PCRE, that would be easy.

Comment: ok..yeah..that is the constraint,  i thought js would have some solution through just regex..meanwhile i will use ur solution.

Comment: Good, once you find it working well enough, please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use 2 reg ex:
First Reg ex fetches the non-hashed lines:

```
^[^#][a\db\s]+
```

and then another reg ex for fetching individual words(from each line):

```
^a\db\s
```